# Outlook: how to create template which duplicates recipient address in link in email content?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2007, email-client, email-templates

I am new with outlook. I would like to create a template with a link inside. The link would have a variable which would be equal to the email address of the recipient.
Is it possible to do it? if so how?

PS: I know nothing about VB, macro... but willing to learn if not too complicated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a dynamic template. Instead, you can create a template and after creating an Outlook based on the template you may correct the link in the body. The [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865637.aspx) method of the Application class creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item.

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate() 
  Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem  
  Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\statusrep.oft")   
  MyItem.Display 
End Sub 

Sub CreateTemplate() 
  Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem  
  Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
  MyItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
  MyItem.To = "Dan Wilson" 
  MyItem.Display 
  MyItem.SaveAs "C:\statusrep.oft", OlSaveAsType.olTemplate 
End Sub
```

> I know nothing about VB, macro... but willing to learn if not too complicated

I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in that case. Then you will find a lot of HOW TO articles in the [How do I... (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863719(v=office.15).aspx) section in MSDN. See also [Concepts (Outlook 2013 developer reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868025(v=office.15).aspx).

Finally, you may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article heplful.